# Core Data in swift. App loses data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am confused by the way that my app is working.
Main part of app is log of fuel fill ups with some statistics. It uses swift and core data.
But for some reason on few devices sometimes it loses user data when app is closed (not putted to background)  - i can't understand why. Also i can't see it in emulator or on my devices.
But some of my friends report me this error.

My app is based on this example http://jamesonquave.com/blog/core-data-in-swift-tutorial-part-3/.

My app is not translated to english so i don't know is it ok to put link to it here.

How can it be that core data is empty when user closes app or reloaded his device?

Comment: You will need to post some code for us to be able to help.

Comment: What part of code is needed? My app is based on example that can be found by link in my question. You need to know that on my device app is working great and i tried it in emulator with iOS7. I want to know - how is it possible to lose Core Data?

Comment: We can't look through an entire tutorial to find what you may have done wrong. Post the relevant Core Data code from your app, e.g., where do you save the context.

Answer (score 3):

Did you call the save method on your main managed object context?

In Xcode projet template, there is a method called when your application terminates that should save:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    [self saveContext];
}
```

For some reasons, this saveContext method can fail or not be called. In that case, the database could be empty if you never saved the context yourself.

For instance after inserting or updating data in the managedObjectContext, you could call:

```
NSError *error = nil
[self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
```

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same problem recently, even with `self.saveContext()` in the `applicationWillTerminate` method in `appDelegate`, I found that I was not saving values in all attributes of Entity. When I saved data in all of attributes, I did not lose data when relaunching the app.